# Angular async await in service not working

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

I have a service which stores user information from backend in local storage. I want the storage call to finish and then have the code continue, as I need to access data from local storage right away.

My code for the service:

```
 async setAccount(){
      if(this.globals.AccountId==0)
      {
          console.log("Account Id is 0");
          if(localStorage.getItem('AccountDetails')){
              console.log("Local Storage is there");
            let AccDetails=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('AccountDetails'));
            this.globals.AccountId=AccDetails["AccountId"];
          }
          else{
            console.log("No local storage found");
            let AccountObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.authService.getAccount()));
            let AzureId: string = AccountObj["accountIdentifier"];
            console.log(AzureId);
            const sendObj: GetAccountByIdQuery = {
              AzureAccountId: AzureId
            };
            console.log("Sending Backend request");
            let res=await this.getAccountById(JSON.stringify(sendObj));
            console.log(res);
            this.globals.AccountId=res["AccountId"];
            console.log(this.globals.AccountId);
            localStorage.setItem('AccountDetails', JSON.stringify(res));                
          }
      }          
  }

    async getAccountById(sendObject: string) { // : Observable<string> {
        console.log("Backend request");
        return await this.http.post<string>(this.AccountUrl + 'GetAccountById',
              sendObject, this.httpOptions)
            .pipe(
                retry(3) // retry a failed request up to 3 times
        ).toPromise();
}
```

I am accessing method as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-layout',
  templateUrl: './home-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-layout.component.css']
})
export class HomeLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private authService: MsalService, private accountService: AzureAccountService, private globals: Globals) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.authService.getAccount()));
    this.setAccount();
    console.log("HomeLayout " + this.globals.AccountId);
  }

  async setAccount() {
    await this.accountService.setAccount();
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error or the issue in its current state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jason is in the right way, you can declare the ngOnInit like this :

```
 async ngOnInit() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.authService.getAccount()));
    await this.setAccount();
    console.log("HomeLayout " + this.globals.AccountId);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this.setAccount() returns a promise you aren’t waiting for.  Since ngOnInit() isn’t an async function you need to use .then()